# how to generate unique id in google app engine for java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

am trying to store a list of files dynamically in google app engine. I can view the list of files in the data store viewer with the name and default id/name in it (Say id/name=4002), if i want to retieve this id (id/name=4002) is there any function provided for this by google?. Also can i use some unique id generators manually adding inside the viewer?. Suggest me an idea.

Answer (score 2):

The viewer is just a helpful tool, don't start to use it as a way to create entities directly as some types you can't enter. Build a frontend.

If you create the model with a specific ID:

```
new_Model = model(id="SomeValue")
```

you can later on get it with that id with [get by id](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id).

```
m = get_by_id("SomeValue")
#get_by_id(id, parent=None, app=None, namespace=None, **ctx_options)
```

The ID numbers generated by GAE are guaranteed unique. You can also generate and reserve a series of unique [numeric keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#numeric_keys).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, am storing the data by program only. In that am getting some file like this `BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");` and storing it like this `fileinput.setProperty("Input File", blobKey);` here fileinput is an entity. now if i want to add an unique id for each file upload how can i do it.

Comment: TBH It's been a while since I used the blobstore but BlobInfo entities are readonly, so you'll have to create (I guess) a parallel record in the datastore that stores additional info. NDB has a BlobKeyProperty I expect exactly for this purpose. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties

Comment: ok fine i have seen some info for python [link]https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get[/link] but dint get any for java do you have any idea.

Comment: sorry, no, I don't do Java :P. I'll retag your question. All the documentation is mirrored for Java and Python so if it's there for Python there will be something similar for Java.

Comment: not so if you look reference section in python it shows various info under the section storage but in java it jus shows you API reference alone thats the prob for me.

Comment: Lucky I chose python then! I'm sure someone will know, just hang on.